# Parse server side enum with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pull the value of an enum I have on the server in javascript.  Right now I'm trying to use razor inside of the javascript to pull the value.

```
var test = '@Enum.Parse(typeof(Enums.OrganizationEntityTypes), ' + currentValue  + ')'
```

currentValue being a javascript parameter.  Compiler doesn't like me adding the currentValue in there... Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: The other answer is good, but misses a few points. If you were to view the compiler output of a razor page, you will see it it is actually all server-side C# code, injecting any HTML as literal strings. By the time the page is provided to the client (where your Javascript is run), it must already all be *static text content*. You cannot access server-side code from client-side code as all server-side code has already been run (and disposed of) after generating the page for the browser.

Comment: Thanks for further clarifying!